# Move the prefab on the swap direction of the screen touch - unity2D

Tags: position, move, touchscreen, gameobject

I am new to unity and I searched for my expected behavior and implemented up to a certain extend. I have prefabs instantiated in the main game script, and I need to add a direction to the gameObject if the the player touched it and do a swap on to any direction (2D). I need only the selected gameObject to apply the swap.

I added touch recognition in the main game script (*GameManager.cs*), with static Vector2 variables to store `touchStartPosition`, `touchEndPosition` and `touchDirection`. Here is my code for touch detection in Update().

```
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchStartPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            touchEndPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            touchdirection = touchEndPosition - touchStartPosition;
        }
```

And here is what I wrote to check if the touchStartPosition is the gameObject position in the gameObject's update().

```
        //if gameObject is on the touch position
        if(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) == GameManager.touchStartPosition)
        {
            MoveBall();
        }
```

Unfortunately nothing happens for the touched gameObject. Please help me to get this code run. That would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

new Vector2() and GameManager.touchStartPosition will only return true with '==' if they refer to the same object

```
    if(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) == GameManager.touchStartPosition)
    {
        MoveBall();
    }
```

change to

```
    if(transform.position.x == GameManager.touchStartPosition.x && transform.position.y == GameManager.touchStartPosition.y)
    {
        MoveBall();
    }
```

and just to be sure there is overlap add a debug before when testing

```
Debug.Log("tx : " + transform.position.x + " -- ty " + transform.position.y + " -- gmx : " + GameManager.touchStartPosition.x + " -- gmy: " + GameManager.touchStartPosition.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some more and finally got a solution. These are the refinements I did to the code

Replaced `Input.GetTouch(0).position` with

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position)
```

And for the check in each gameObject file, I used the below if condition

```
if(GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(GameManager.touchStartPosition)){}
```

This worked really fine. Thanks all for help